# How to upload helper.py to Tensorflow 2.0 notebook in Google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am very new with TensorFlow 2.0 and python. I tried to run this tutorial [Linear Algebra](https://colab.research.google.com/github/adhiraiyan/DeepLearningWithTF2.0/blob/master/notebooks/02.00-Linear-Algebra.ipynb#scrollTo=of02mDcgUuHQ) but then it asks for uploading helper.py at the get go. How do I do that?

> If you are running this notebook in Google colab, make sure to upload the helpers.py file to your session before running it, but if you are running this in Binder, then you don't have to worry about it. The helpers.py file will be in the notebook folder in GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the helper.py file from github and upload it to the colab session. In the left panel there is a option "files" click on it, then you will see a option upload click it, select the helper.py file and upload. Now you can run run colab notebook.